# How to set android EditText background with gradient effect using xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

Hi i am new to android and this is first time here..
How to set a EditText background from xml with gradient effect.
i have the code for setting background from xml. But this only gives plain background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#ABCDEF"/> 
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
  android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>   

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the gradient tag within shape tag

```
<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:startColor="#FFea5626"
    android:endColor="#80ec9d83"
    android:type="sweep"
    />
```

based on your need you can change the angle
the type you can change to linear also
depends on the start color and end color the gradient effect will look like